# PHP | POST variables with Curl as in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

How to replicate this data post by ajax with curl?

```
  ...
  data: {
    search: JSON.stringify({
    daterange : "custom", 
    daterangecustom  : {
        start   : "2013-03-01T23:59:59",
        end     : "2018-03-01T23:59:59"
      }
    }),
    limit: 50
  },
  ...
```

I dont need the whole code for curl, but only `$params` value:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

I`ve been trying to make this work for a while, with no success. Thanks a lot to anyone with a solution here!!

Comment: Can you show the code of how you were trying to make that work?

Comment: Tried the most basic one: `$params = "search=".'{"country":"US"}';`

Comment: The top code part does not contain a *country* element. Why would you add it then?

Comment: Its not about actual elements, but rather about how it should be implemented. The API, im sending the request to also allows `country` filter, so - because I failed with the more complex request, I tried more simplistic ones. Code supplied in the main question is the final goal.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a little more, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$data = array(
    'search' => array(
        'daterange' => 'custom',
        'daterangecustom' => array(
            'start' => '2013-03-01T23:59:59',
            'end'   => '2018-03-01T23:59:59',
        ),
    ),
    'limit' => 50,
);

$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

The request will look like this:

```
POST /url HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Accept: */*
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 122

{"search":{"daterange":"custom","daterangecustom":{"start":"2013-03-01T23:59:59","end":"2018-03-01T23:59:59"}},"limit":50}
```